# sending key to a process chosen by user without the process being in focus

Tags: c#, winforms

I am unsure on how to send the key chosen by the user to the process chosen by the user as well.
Is there any possible way of doing this?

This is my current code:

```
// Global variables
        private string key;
        private string process;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Get processes and add it to the combo box.
        private void processList_Dropdown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process[] processAll = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process process in processAll)
            {
                processList.Items.Add(process.ProcessName);
            }
        }

        // Add all keys into combo box.
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Array keyValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys));

            foreach (var key in keyValues)
            {
                string keyName = key.ToString();
                keyList.Items.Add(keyName);
            }
        }

        // Assigning the user's chosen key to a global variable.
        private void keyList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            key = keyList.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

        // Assigning the user's chosen key to a global variable.
        private void processList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            process = processList.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
```

I have tried SendKeys but that didn't work for me.

Comment: `SendKeys()` uses `SendInput()` (hence may be restricted by UIPI), so the app needs keyboard focus to receive the keys you're sending. You can use UI Automation (to some to extent, depending on the functionality you're after) to interact with the Windows of other Processes. UI Automation doesn't required focus changes